# Javascript + Spring Boot + Thymeleaf - form validation

Tags: javascript, html, spring

I'm trying to validate password and see if they match using JavaScript if passwords don't match show an error, but some for weird reason is like Javascript is not being detected, just submits the wrong fields.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Reset Your Password</title>

</head>
<body>
<script "text/Javascript">

    document.querySelector('.button').onclick = function (){
        var password = document.querySelector('.password').value,
            confirmPassword = document.querySelector('.confirmPassword').value;

        if(password === ""){
            alert("Field cannot be empty.");
        }
        else if(password !== confirmPassword){
            alert("Password didn't match try again");
        }else if(password === confirmPassword){
            alert("Password match")
        }
    }
</script>
<div class="elelment">
    <h2>Reset Your Password</h2>
    <div class="element-main">
        <h1>Forgot Password</h1>
<form th:action="@{/api/auth/reset_password}" method="post" style="max-width: 350px; margin: 0 auto;">
    <input type="hidden" name="token" th:value="${token}" />
    <div class="border border-secondary rounded p-3">
        <div>
            <p>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="password"
                       placeholder="Enter your new password"  />
            </p>
            <p>
                <input type="password" class="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword"  placeholder="Confirm your new password"
                 />
            </p>
            <p class="text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Change Password" class="button" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="copy-right">
    <p>© 2021 Reset Password Form. All rights reserved</a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

AM not sure why JavaScript is not being detected and being applied to the form to validate the password fields

Comment: Try this , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577326/how-to-solve-typeerror-document-queryselector-is-null

Answer (score 0):

bro try changing your script tag to this:

```
    <script th:inline="javascript">
       //your checking conditions
    </script>
```

Let me know if this works.